# Add class if child element not present

Tags: javascript, jquery

If this works when a class is present...

```
$('.priority').children('.no-priority').addClass('normal');
```

How would I add a class if the child class .no-priority is missing?

Tried code below which does not work

```
if (!$('.priority').children('.no-priority')) {
 $('.priority').addClass('prioritised');
 }
```

Neither does

```
$('.priority').not('.no-priority').addClass('prioritised');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:not()`, `:has()`

```js
$(".priority:not(:has(.no-priority))").addClass("normal")
```

```css
.normal {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="priority">
  <div class="does-not-have-no-priority">
    does not have .no-priority
  </div>
</div>

<div class="priority">
  <div class="no-priority">
    has .no-priority
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use `filter`

```js
$('.priority').filter(function() {
  return $(this).find('.no-priority').length === 0;
}).addClass('normal');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can do this in vanilla javascript:

```js
var priority = document.querySelectorAll('.priority');

for (var i = 0; i < priority.length; i++) {
  if (priority[i].querySelector('.no-priority')) {
    priority[i].classList.add('normal');
  } else {
    priority[i].classList.add('prioritised');
  }
}
```

```css
.priority.normal {
  color: red;
}

.priority.prioritised {
  color: blue; 
}
```

```html
<div class="priority">
  <div class="no-priority">no priority</div>
</div>

<div class="priority">
  <div class="foo">priority</div>
</div>
```